# Does anyone have any examples or suggestions utilizing Atmel's ATMEGA2560 and external interrupt's?

Tags: atmega, atmel, interrupts

I am trying to utilize an ATMEGA2560 and it's interrupt.  I have some code that must execute until a button is pressed at which time I need the code to stop and wait for another button press to continue.

Is anyone familiar with this type of circuit and the interrupts?

Here is what I am currently referencing for the [ATMEGA2560 interrupts](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=67358&start=0).

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have some code that must execute uninterrupted until a command is received on a port(or a button press indication is received, then the code must pause until the afore mentioned is received again.

Comment: From your original post this action is not perfectly clear. When you just say you want it to stop there is no reason that the code could not be peppered with statements to wait on a button to go high. your comment makes clear that you specifically need this interrupt functionality. It may seem minor but clarification like that can avoid posts like lonetech's.

Comment: @Kortuk I agree, I was very vague in my statement of needs, I then provided little of my background work or example code.  In the future I will try to be less vague and more clear regarding the design of my questions. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Just trying to help out. I am glad you still got the answer you were needing. often people on this site over complicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ LoneTech: I figured this site was to help people. Not put them down for lack of information, but to provide it for them if the need is there.  Also, Interrupts can be used to interrupt other code without hurting the speed of your main loop.  If your button is supposed to change a process and your main loop is controlling a wave or something.  INT0 could be used.  You also don't know what other operations this individual plans on using it for.

@ Michael: This code took me a while to track down and understand as well.  I have written code for AVRs for 5+ years now and for PC 13+ years.  Its amazing how little documentation is there at your fingertips.  I ran across a nice tutorial and finally it clicked.

```
void InitINT0()
{
    // Enable INT0 External Interrupt
    EIMSK |= 1<<INT0;

    // Falling-Edge Triggered INT0 - This will depend on if you
    // are using a pullup resistor or a pulldown resistor on your
    // button and port
    MCUCR |= 1<<ISC01;
}

int main(void)
{
    //Init Timer
    InitINT0();

    //Which Interrupt pin you need to enable
    //can be found in the datasheet, look at the pin
    //configuration, usually within the first 5 pages
    //track down INT0 - which is PORTD pin 0.
    //This needs to be an input.
    DDRD &= 0;

    // Enable Interrupts
    sei();

    //Givin that PORTD0 is the INT0, your button should
    //be hooked up to it.

    while(1)
    {
        //Do your operation
    }
}

// External Interrupt 0 ISR
ISR(INT0_vect) 
{
    while (/*Button is down*/) //0 is the pin for your button
    { 
        //Pause your operation , this will pause everything though
        //because Interrupts take priority over pretty much everything
        //This includes other interrupts and your main loop
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly how I would have approached this.

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of people are familiar with it, yes, as it's no different than any other AVR. The details depend on which compiler and library you use, and you should check their documentation, as well as the datasheet. AVRfreaks, which you linked to yourself, has lots more on the subject and is probably a better place to ask if you get stuck (rather than just never started to read up...). For instance, [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) is used with GCC.

As a sidenote, the situation you describe doesn't make apparent why you'd need interrupts. It's typically easier to just poll the button.

Comment: First,  to answer your inference, I have indeed researched the use of interrupts.  It still remains unclear to me how to utilize them.  As for this forum, Is it not the purpose of this forum to provide a platform for those whom are seeking guidance to seek assistance from others with experience?  Your answer is simply a curt suggestion that i have not researched enough and that if I had I wouldn't need to ask a question here.  If everyone could answer their own questions, there would be no need for any of the stackexchange sites!

Comment: @michael Eakins, I am glad you found the help you need. The point of this site is not only to help but become the definitive source for what you need help with.

Comment: I may have taken a needlessly harsh approach, yes. But I saw very little of planning - the chip is presented, code needs are not. For instance, the compiler question is still unanswered and does affect how you use interrupts. If I did not think at least some of what I mentioned or linked could provide a little guidance, I would not have posted as an answer.

Comment: when I first saw the question without any extra detail I assumed that the asker had not thought it through, with more info I see otherwise. It happens. I would like to say that assuming the asker always knows what they want is valid, but often answers like yours are accepted as they did not think it through.